# magento 2 send data or variable from the controller to phtml template file directly in custom module?

Tags: magento2

Tried every thing to send data but not work. In the index controller what can i use to send the data to template file.

```
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $this->_view->loadLayout();

    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    $we =  $this->getRequest()->getParams();         

   // echo "<pre>";print_r($we);        
     if(!empty($we['ripple_email'])){
        $register_email= $we['ripple_email']; 
        if(!class_exists('afclass'))
        include_once 'afclass.php';  
        // $curl_info = new afclass;
        $asset_id = Afclass::before_registration($register_email); 
        $value =225; 
        $block = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('module\Block\Adminhtml\CustomBlock');

        $block->setFeedback($value);

     }

  $this->_view->renderLayout();
}
```

}

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: pthml template file i get it using  $this->getFeedback;   @Abdul plz suggest the idea

Comment: Refer this please.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145816/magento-2-how-to-send-data-from-controller-to-block-and-display-on-front-end/298887#298887

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your block with `$block = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('module\Block\Adminhtml\CustomBlock');`, you can pass data to it using the 3rd argument to the createBlock function. For example:

```
$block = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('module\Block\Adminhtml\CustomBlock', 'block name', ['data' => ['MyData' => 'value']]);
```

The data will then be accessible to your block through the $data array that is passed to it's constructor.

Comment: i got it simply change the  createBlock('module\Block\Adminhtml\CustomBlock')   by  createBlock('blockname');

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `assign()` function

```
$block = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('module\Block\Adminhtml\CustomBlock');
$block->assign([
    'bar' => 'foo'
]);
```

so in custom template file you could use

```
<?php echo $bar; //output 'foo' ?>
```

The `assign()` function could be useful when you don't need to create block instance, for example because you have already block in layout and you retrieve it with

```
$block = $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('foobar');
```