# Magento 2 : How to send data from controller to block and display on front end

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2-migration-tool, magento2-dev-beta

**I have used the following code**

```
<?php

namespace Inchoo\Helloworld\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Inchoo\Helloworld\Model\PostFactory;

class View extends Action
{


    protected $_modelPostFactory;


    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PostFactory $modelPostFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_modelPostFactory = $modelPostFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $postModel = $this->_modelPostFactory->create();

        // Load the item with ID is 1
        $item = $postModel->load(1);
      //  var_dump($item->getData());

        // Get news collection
        $postCollection = $postModel->getCollection();
        // Load all data of collection
         var_dump($postCollection->getData());

    }
}
```

**I have collected the database table field values using the above code. Now i need to send the to block. And need to display in front end**

**please help me**

Comment: It is not proper way to send data controller to block and display in front-end. To fulfill your requirement @Sneha Panchal gives you enough Idea how you can achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

For sending data from controller to block, you can use **registry**

**Controller**

```
protected $_coreRegistry = null;

public function __construct(
      ....

        \Magento\Framework\Registry $_coreRegistry
    ) {
       .....
        $this->_coreRegistry = $_coreRegistry;
        ....
    }
   public function execute()
    {

        $postModel = $this->_modelPostFactory->create();

        // Load the item with ID is 1
        $item = $postModel->load(1);
      //  var_dump($item->getData());

        // Get news collection
        $postCollection = $postModel->getCollection();
        // Load all data of collection
         var_dump($postCollection->getData());
       $this->_coreRegistry->register('data_test', $postCollection);

    }
```

**Block**

```
 protected $_coreRegistry = null;


public function __construct(
      ....

        \Magento\Framework\Registry $_coreRegistry
    ) {
       .....
        $this->_coreRegistry = $_coreRegistry;
        ....
    }
   public function test()
    {
        $postCollection = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('data_test');
    }
```

Comment: Usage of Registry is disadvised after Magento 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

In controller, define code like below. And mention block name you declared in 
`{route id}_{controller name}_{action name}.xml`

```
$resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
$resultPage->getLayout()
           ->getBlock('[block_name]')
           ->setDataTest($dataCollection);
```

Now in template file

```
<?php
print_r($block->getDataTest()->getData());
?>
```

Comment: Seems not to work in Magento 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Your layout file name must be :

```
{module name}_{controller name}_{action name}.xml
```

Then in your layout file please use below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <body>     
        <referenceContainer name="content">         
            <block class="{company name}\{Module name}\Block\Index" name="block_name">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>      
    </body>
</page>
```

In your controller action file use below code :

```
<?php
namespace {company name}\{module name}\Controller;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $_cacheTypeList;


    protected $_cacheState;

    protected $_cacheFrontendPool;


    protected $resultPageFactory;


    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\StateInterface $cacheState,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
        $this->_cacheState = $cacheState;
        $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $this->resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();  
        return $this->resultPage;

    }
}
```

Now please create relate block file and create any function like:

```
    public function getNewsCollection() {
    $postModel = $this->_modelPostFactory->create();

        // Load the item with ID is 1
        $item = $postModel->load(1);
      //  var_dump($item->getData());

        // Get news collection
        $postCollection = $postModel->getCollection();
return $postCollection;
            }
```

Now in your template file call above function as :

```
print_r($this->getNewsCollection()->getData());
```

So in your case you need to load your all collection in block file function and then you can get that collection function in template file same as i explained above.

Comment: Thansks for posting. If i hit the template file it shows only blank page for me.

Comment: i cant access $this->_modelPostFactory->create(); in block file

Comment: first of all check your template file is called or not by echo anything